# Allow users to edit their own posts even if they have other edits in queue

Tags: bug, edits, suggested-edits

The following just happened:

1. I did some cleanup on a site where I have < 2k rep. I had to do the edits in batches, as I could only do a few at a time, and wait for them to be approved.
2. While waiting for one batch to be approved, I posted a question.
3. I then noticed a somewhat serious error in this question of mine. I tried to correct the error, but I wasn't even able to initiate the edit. As soon as I clicked the "edit" button, there was a white screen with text telling me I had to wait until the reviews of the other edits were done. It's the same thing that would have happened had I tried to edit someone else's post at that point.

When editing my own posts, I don't think this limitation should apply. Having edits pending in the review queue shouldn't alter users' ability to edit their own posts.

Comment: Why don't you visit their chat room and ask for approval of pending edits?

Comment: Well, reviewing edits don't require special knowledge as long as you didn't change the content in a way that requires it. I am not sure about SciFi SE, but usually there are high-rep users including moderators in a chat room.

Comment: @Rathony I agree, it mostly doesn't require special knowledge.

Comment: You can unilaterally approve or reject edits to your own posts. Go review the edit, then you'll be able to edit again.

Comment: @ArtOfCode The edits that were waiting in queue were edits *by me* made *to other people's* posts. As for the edit I was unable to do, (to my own post), I wasn't even able to initiate it. As soon as I clicked the "edit" button, there was a white screen with text telling me I had to wait until the reviews of the other edits were done. It's the same thing that would have happened had I tried to edit someone else's post at that point.

Comment: Oh, right. Yeah, that makes more sense, but the <s>feature</s> bug doesn't.

Comment: Pretty sure this is in fact a bug. You should always be able to edit your own posts. Developers are looking into it.

Comment: @TimPost Thanks for the edit :) And for looking into it :)

Comment: Which site was this on?

Comment: @AdamLear SF&FSE

Comment: I cannot reproduce this; I believe this has been fixed in the past year.

Comment: @Glorfindel I guess then that we should ping the developers to ask them, so they can change the status of this question?

Comment: You can try to ping Tim Post or Adam Lear (as they've responded here). They (or somebody else) might've fixed it 'by accident'.

Comment: @AdamLear Hi, has this been fixed? According to Glorfindel, it can no longer be reproduced. Can we change the status of the post?

Comment: @TimPost Hi, has this been fixed? According to Glorfindel, it can no longer be reproduced. Can we change the status of the post?

Comment: @AdamLear has this been fixed?

Answer (score 2):

I also can’t reproduce this along with @Glorfindel so this has probably been resolved, but with no moderator confirmation it’s hard to say for sure.